# How to add spaces between numbers in string with word and integer?

Tags: java, string, integer, space

Having string like this

> "APM35 2FAST4YOU -5ABBA STEVE0.5&Tom"

and using regular expression Im not getting result as I want to. How can I add space before and after of each integer?
Code:

```
String s = "APM35 2FAST4YOU -5ABBA STEVE0.5&Tom";
s = s.replaceAll("(\\d)([A-Za-z])", "\\1 \\2");
System.out.println(s);
```

I'm getting such result:

```
APM35 1 2AST1 2OU -1 2BBA STEVE0.5&Tom
```

and I'd like get this string as result:

```
APM 35 2 FAST 4 YOU -5 ABBA STEVE 0.5 &Tom
```

Comment: IMO I wouldn't use `String#replaceAll` for this.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza What would you do?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Feel free to give me any suggest which come to ur head.

Comment: I would traverse the `String` char by char and defining the difference between a number (note that it can contain a dot `.` in it) and a non-numeric `String` (because a symbol like `&` is not inside `[A-Za-z]`). Also, you don't know which could come first.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Regex would be shorter

Comment: @JimmyT. propose such RegEx then :).

Comment: To get the behavior he describes, I suspect the letter character class would be something more like, `[^0-9]`, instead of `[A-Za-z]`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The answers already give good examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
s.replaceAll("([^\\d-]?)(-?[\\d\\.]+)([^\\d]?)", "$1 $2 $3").replaceAll(" +", " ");
```

First regexp can generate some extra spaces, they are removed by second one.

Comment: Pretty code, isnt it better to remove all additional spaces with `replaceAll(" {2,}", " ")` then `replaceAll(" +", " ")`

Answer (score 4):

You could do it in two steps:

```
String s = "APM35 2FAST4YOU -5ABBA STEVE0.5&Tom";
//add a space after the numbers
String step1 = s.replaceAll("(-?\\d\\.?\\d*)([^\\d\\s])", "$1 $2");
//add a space before the numbers
String step2 = step1.replaceAll("([^0-9\\-\\s])(-?\\d\\.?\\d*)", "$1 $2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I wrote too fast, but I might as well ask: are you sure Java's regex API is able to identify a group (\1 and \2)?

Because it seems that parts of the string are replaced by actual 1s and 2s so this might not be the correct syntax.

(And it seems that you are only checking for numbers followed by text, not the other way arround.)

Comment: I think it sould be $1 and $2.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the expression "(-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)"

(0.5 is no integer, if you only want integers (-?[0-9]+) should be enough)

and replace it with " \1 " or " $1 " (Dont know which is the right one for Java) (Spaces before and after)